# rails db:seed erroring with ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Category must exist

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

OK, so I swear this seed file was working before, but now whenever I try to run the rails db:seed command I get the error:

```
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Category must exist
/home/krefey/dev/sonar/db/seeds.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
/home/krefey/dev/sonar/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/home/krefey/dev/sonar/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/krefey/dev/sonar/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
```

I am using the latest rails version and my database is MySQL

my seed file is:

```
Category.create!(name: 'Miniatures')
Category.create!(name: 'Cardgames')
Category.create!(name: 'Boardgames')
Category.create!(name: 'RPG')
Game.create!(name: 'Warhammer 40,000', category_id: Category.find_by(name:'Miniatures'))
Game.create!(name: 'Age of Sigmar', category_id: Category.find_by(name: 'Miniatures'))
Game.create!(name: 'Necromunda', category_id: Category.find_by(name: 'Miniatures'))
Game.create!(name: 'Warmachine', category_id: Category.find_by(name: 'Miniatures'))
Game.create!(name: 'Hordes', category_id: Category.find_by(name: 'Miniatures'))
Game.create!(name: 'Infinity', category_id: Category.find_by(name: 'Miniatures'))
Game.create!(name: 'Munchkin', category_id: Category.find_by(name: 'Cardgames'))
Game.create!(name: 'Cardgamess Against Humanity', category_id: Category.find_by(name: 'Cardgames'))
Game.create!(name: 'Choking Hazard', category_id: Category.find_by(name: 'Cardgames'))
Game.create!(name: 'Poker', category_id: Category.find_by(name: 'Cardgames'))
Game.create!(name: 'Bridge', category_id: Category.find_by(name: 'Cardgames'))
Game.create!(name: 'Risk', category_id: Category.find_by(name: 'Boardgames'))
Game.create!(name: 'Twighlight Imperium', category_id: Category.find_by(name: 'Boardgames'))
Game.create!(name: 'Shadespire', category_id: Category.find_by(name: 'Boardgames'))
Game.create!(name: 'Settlers of Catan', category_id: Category.find_by(name: 'Boardgames'))
Game.create!(name: 'Carcasonne', category_id: Category.find_by(name: 'Boardgames'))
Game.create!(name: 'Dungeons & Dragons', category_id: Category.find_by(name: 'RPG'))
Game.create!(name: 'Pathfinder', category_id: Category.find_by(name: 'RPG'))
Game.create!(name: '7th Sea', category_id: Category.find_by(name: 'RPG'))
Game.create!(name: 'Legend of the 5 Rings', category_id: Category.find_by(name: 'RPG'))
Game.create!(name: 'GURPS', category: Category.find_by(name: 'RPG'))
```

category model:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :games
  validates :name, inclusion: { in: %w(Miniatures RPG Cardgames Boardgames),
    message: "%{value} is not a valid game type"}, presence: true
end
```

game model:

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category

  def self.search(search)
    where("content LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
  end
end
```

schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20171130120931) do

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "games", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.bigint "category_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_games_on_category_id"
  end

  add_foreign_key "games", "categories"
end
```

The error seems to be complaining about the Category.find_by part.  But I don't get why.  The category model is there and exists in the schema.  I can successfully drop the table, create the table and run the migrations, but then it fails when I try to run the db:seed command (or it gets to the db:seed part of a db:reset command).

If I add the

```
optional: true
```

code to the game model, then the seed works, but the category_id field isn't populated and shows as nil.  So, where am I going wrong?  Why can't I seem to populate the foreign key column of category_id in the games table?

Comment: Can you try `Game.create!(name: 'Warhammer 40,000', category: Category.find_by(name:'Miniatures'))`? NOTE: I replaced `category_id` with `category`

Comment: This looks like it has worked, thanks Jagdeep.  I might try the refactoring mentioned in another comment too if I have to rebuild the test DB.

Answer (score 0):

I think such refactoring will solve your stacktrace and make your seeds MUCH MORE readable:

```
miniatures_category = Category.create!(name: 'Miniatures')
...
Game.create!(name: 'Warhammer 40,000', category: miniatures_category)
Game.create!(name: 'Age of Sigmar', category: miniatures_category)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can assign a model object to a ID. Two correct possibilities could be:

```
Game.create!(name: 'Warhammer 40,000', category: Category.find_by(name:'Miniatures'))
# or also possible, but ugly:
Game.create!(name: 'Warhammer 40,000', category_id: Category.find_by(name:'Miniatures').id)
```

As stated by AntonTkachov, you should refactor your code at all, to get rid of all those `find_by` calls.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *create* as described on [Association proxies in Active Record](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-create)  as follows:

```
# db/seeds.rb

miniatures = Category.create(name: 'Miniatures')
miniatures.games.create([
  { name: 'Warharmmer 40,000' },
  { name: 'Age of Sigmar' },
  { name: 'Necromunda' }
])

card = Category.create(name: 'Cardgames')
card.games.create([
  { name: 'Muchkin' },
  { name: 'Cardgames Against Humanity' },
  { name: 'Chocking Hazard' }
])
```

I suspect that the reason why your seeds file was working before is because you were not using Rails 5 which makes the belongs_to association **required by default**. See this post by [Abhishek Jain](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html) for more information.